# In a SELECT how can I return a mask of a jsonb column according to same/similar string as for json-mask?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb

We have a jsonb column acting as a document store, and do our object key filtering in the application.

Our jsonb column contains nested arrays and objects with no consistent structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(id serial, doc jsonb);
INSERT INTO test(doc) values ('{"name": "name1", "custom":{ "role": "admin", "valid": true}, "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}');
INSERT INTO test(doc) values ('{"name": "name2", "custom":{ "role": "admin", "valid": true}, "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}');
INSERT INTO test(doc) values ('{"name": "name3", "custom":{ "role": "user", "valid": true}, "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}');
INSERT INTO test(doc) values ('{"custom":{ "role": "app", "valid": "on_tuesdays"}}');
INSERT INTO test(doc) values ('{"name": "name4", "custom":{ "role": "admin", "valid": true}, "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]}');
```

([dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0))

We use [json-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-mask) to filter the response:

```js
import mask from 'json-mask'

let str = 'name,custom(role,valid)'
let output = [];
const results = await runSql();
for(let row of results){
  output.push({ 
    doc: mask(row.doc, str) 
  })
}
```

output:

```json
[{
  doc: {
    name: 'name1',
    custom: {
        role: 'admin',
        valid: true
    }
  }
},{
  doc: {
    name: 'name2',
    custom: {
        role: 'admin',
        valid: true
    }
  }
},{
  doc: {
    name: 'name3',
    custom: {
        role: 'user',
        valid: true
    }
  }
},{
  doc: {
    custom: {
        role: 'app',
        valid: "on_tuesdays"
    }
  }
},{
  doc: {
    name: 'name4',
    custom: {
        role: 'admin',
        valid: true
    }
  }
}]
```

**How can I do the masking in SQL instead? Do I need to build separate jsonb objects for each key/path, then merge them all together using `||`, or is there a better way?**

From the [postgresql json docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) it seems like jsonb_object_agg or jsonb_build_object could potentially do what I need, but I would need to  destructure the mask string and do some type of looping for the nested objects.

something like (doesnt account for arrays):

```
select
  jsonb_build_object(
    'name', test.doc->>'name',
    'custom' , (
       jsonb_build_object(
         'role', test.doc->'custom'->>'role'
       )
    )
  )
...
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I'm having trouble phrasing the question correctly, or using the right terms; I've googled alot but I dont have anything to really try that fits what I need (thats why no error messages to post).

Comment: ["9.16. JSON Functions and Operators"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) is a start.

Comment: Added a bit more info on where I _think_ I should be going. Ideally somebody knows of an extension or function that accomplishes what I'm trying to do

Comment: That doesn't look too bad, does it? Keep working on it (add the array handling and stuff) and that might be it. But I still don't understand where your *exact* problem or question is. It's still all very vague and more like a specification dump...

Comment: I definitely wish I could be clearer! It _seemed_ like a problem that many people would have encountered (return less data from nested jsonb) and I was just missing the phrase to google. I'll update the question as I try building my own version

Comment: I don't think it's possible to automatically translate a `json-mask` query path string into an (efficient) postgresql query, due to the implicit array handling. If the mask would specify on which level an array was expected, you could do it. Or you need a schema of your data…

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with. At least the output is precisely the same.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object(
  'name', test.doc->>'name',
  'custom' , (
       jsonb_build_object(
         'role', test.doc->'custom'->>'role',
         'valid', test.doc->'custom'->>'valid'
       )
   )
))) from test;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h2mwTcBni48KgpoCJEf1Fe/0).